# Can I use python code for displaying graph in flutter app?

Tags: python, flutter, matplotlib, heatmap

I made a heatmap using python matplotlib. Now I want to build a frontend in flutter and integrate that python backend in it. Is this possible? If yes, then how? If its not possible, what can the alternative be?

Answer (score 0):

u could consider using iframe tag in your flutter app alternatively you would need to build a rest endpoint and use flutter charts library to make your work consistent

Comment: I don't think flutter has inline functionality for graphs and plots as far as I know.

Comment: u can redirect your  users to another website

Comment: I was able to do that. But we're looking to display it in our app. Like we tap a button and its displayed.

Comment: what of the iframe option?